# How to execute a script when workspace changed?

Tags: automation, lxde

I use devilspie to arrange the windows of monitoring tools (htop,ifop,iotop,nethogs, bmon) at the third workspace.

In case I need the details about some process activity, I switch to the third workspace and watch all I need immediately. It is very handful to me. But these tools consume resources of my week ATOM box which I want to be free when I don't use the third desktop.

That is why I'm looking for a way to stop (kill -STOP) these monitoring processes when I move from the third desktop and coninue them (kill -CONT) when I come back. I figure out there might be a kind of hooks in DE which trigger when desktops switch.

I use LXDE in Lucid. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking for a [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) signal that is emitted whenever you switch workspaces.

Try to run `dbus-monitor` to check which signals are emitted while you do that. See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38733/how-to-read-dbus-monitor-output) about how to read the `dbus-monitor` output.

There are [Python bindings for D-Bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) which you can use to write a script that closes existing windows when this signal is emitted. You can kill a process using Python's [os.kill](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill) function.

Comment: Thank you for that idea.I checked it out and found that no event is generated when workspace changed. Seems like LXDE does not support dbus.