# How to get a proxy for DBus object that is not well known?

Tags: python, application-development, dbus, libdbusmenu

I'm endeavouring to use dbus to react to a particular signal (user clicks on an appindicator menu on the unity top panel). From using dbus-monitor, I've found the relevant signal that I'd like to react to:

```
sender=:1.96 -> dest=:1.232 serial=2091 path=/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/myapp/Menu; interface=com.canonical.dbusmenu; member=AboutToShowGroup
array [
   int32 9
]
```

Then my plan was to do the following with python:

```
dbus_proxy = bus.get_object ("BUS.NAME", "PATH")
interface = dbus.Interface (proxy, "INTERFACE")
interface.connect_to_signal ("SIGNAL", my_function)

def my_function:
    # react
```

In order to understand dbus, I've been using the following two articles:
 [the dbus-python tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) and
 [How to read dbus-monitor output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38733/how-to-read-dbus-monitor-output)

However, I'm a bit confused as to what values I should be using for bus name, path, interface and signal in my code. I've tried poking around in qdbus in order to work out the correct values, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I think I've been thrown off because get_object requires a "well-known" name, but all I've got is the numerical unique identifiers for sender, dest.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should typically be fairly easy, but it seems that DBus objects are created dynamically for their indicators. Reference Transmission with an indicator enabled in D-Feet to see. The real problem here is how to `bus.get_object` for your "myapp" bus name.

Comment: Thanks for recommending d-feet. It's a highly useful tool for viewing available signals and methods. Through it, I realised 'AbouttoShowGroup' is actually a method, not a signal. This was something I over-looked in the dbus-monitor output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [add_signal_receiver](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.connection.Connection-class.html#add_signal_receiver) function can be used without specifying a bus name. This can be useful for capturing signals when the bus name, interface or specific signal name is unknown.

```
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()

session_bus.add_signal_receiver(self.do_something,
                                signal_name=None,
                                dbus_interface=None,
                                bus_name=None, 
                                path=None)
```

The above code calls the do_something method every time a signal is received on the session bus.

In my original question, I stated I wanted to respond to 'AboutToShowGroup'. However, after closer inspection of the 'com.canonical.dbusmenu' interface, I realised it is in fact a method and not a signal. I have since chosen another signal to react to.

Comment: What signal did you use to determine that the user has clicked on your AppIndicator icon?

Comment: I could not find any signals that seemed relevant for clicking on the AppIndicator icon. Instead, I re-thought my design approach and decided I wouldn't react to the menu being opened, but instead to other system events that would require my app to act.

Comment: Shah, while there is still no 'proper' solution for determining when a user has clicked on an AppIndicator icon. [Sampo555](https://launchpad.net/~sampo555) has come up with a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/screenlets/+bug/522152/comments/11), reacting to the Unity Panel Service dbus.

Comment: Thanks, interesting read.  I gave up on it as well and moved to a different approach, but if I revisit this area it will be a good point to start experimenting.