# How to use refresh command with freedesktop services?

Tags: 15.10, battery, udev

I want to use the refresh command on this [here](http://upower.freedesktop.org/docs/Device.html)

But i do not know how to do it, please help.

Comment: I know that you are still tracking you battery refresh problem from your other questions, but such type of question is not useful for other users. Please make a look on   https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

```
dbus-send --print-reply \
  --system \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower \
  /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 \
  org.freedesktop.UPower.Device.Refresh
```

Output example:

```
method return time=1453211890.054932 sender=:1.55 -> destination=:1.209 serial=318 reply_serial=2
```

It is good to read little about DBus:

- [How to read dbus-monitor output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38733/how-to-read-dbus-monitor-output/38796#38796)
- [D-Bus Tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html)

You can take a venture using `d-feet` tool :).

Comment: Have to wait 2 hours to post bounty, will do it then :)