# View full message from gnome notifications area

Tags: notification, gnome-shell

The Gnome Notifications area only shows the title and a portion of the first line of a message.

Clicking on the message in the Notifications area simply removes the message.
I've tried looking at the Logs, but do not see the message there.

How can I view the full message?

In the screen shot below, there is a message about network discovery, but I can't see the rest of the message.

[image]

Comment: this is https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776048

Comment: Here is the new bug report, go upvote it: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/753 (the old bug report is on Bugzilla and has expired)

Comment: Thank you for linking the bug report; I have up-voted. I encourage others to do so as well.

Comment: How about `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/notifications`? Someone mentioned that today in the Matrix chat GNOME channel. For me that file has _some_ of my notifications, maybe only (evolution) calendar event reminders.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

If what you are looking is to see the full message somewhere, the GNOME extension ["Notifications to file"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1840/notifications-to-session-file/) allows you to store the notifications to a file of choice.

**Expert mode**

If you are looking to see the full message in the notification list of your screenshot, you may want to change the CSS of that specific section of GNOME. There are some tutorials that help to do this, but I do not recommend to go this route unless you know what you are doing. You can see the documentation on [Gnome Shell wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Development).

You can find all CSS related to these notifications on the file `gnome-shell.css` of your gnome-shell theme, located on:

`/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`

The CSS related to these specific notifications are under the CSS class `.message-list`.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I could compile the theme from source (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/tree/master/data/theme/gnome-shell-sass). I see quite a few references to `.message-list` in `_common.scss`. But none of them specify the height of the notification. Any suggestions on what to add or modify?

Answer (score 1):

There are various add-ons that might help.

This stops apps removing their own:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1335/grown-up-notifications/

This keeps them visible until clicked:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/41/permanent-notifications/

This shows a counter:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1386/notification-counter/

And so on. You might need to try some combination to see if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

**A bullet-proof method to see all notifications, full notification messages**

(The method provides access to all, full notification messages.
A finer grained handling of them is possible).

The "basic" command `dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"` will show info on every notification.
For instance, if in terminal #1 I execute that command, and in terminal #2 I execute `notify-send -u normal 'testing'`, I get in terminal #1

```
method call time=1650533140.066199 sender=:1.357 -> destination=:1.69 serial=6 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=GetServerInformation
method call time=1650533140.067533 sender=:1.69 -> destination=:1.49 serial=305 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=GetServerInformation
method call time=1650533140.122757 sender=:1.357 -> destination=:1.69 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   uint32 0
   string ""
   string "testing"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "urgency"
         variant             byte 1
      )
   ]
   int32 -1
method call time=1650533140.131442 sender=:1.69 -> destination=:1.49 serial=310 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   uint32 0
   string ""
   string "testing"
   string ""
   array [
   ]
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "urgency"
         variant             byte 1
      )
      dict entry(
         string "sender-pid"
         variant             uint32 87009
      )
   ]
   int32 -1
```

From this point on, you could handle that information as you like.
For instance, you could:

1. Send that info to a log file (surely needed). **Note: This is enough to view the full messages, as requested in the OP**
2. `grep`/`awk`/`sed`, etc. the output
3. Place your command in your `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.
4. Postprocess the timestamp.
5. Automate maintenance of the log file (cleaning old notifications, etc.)

I don't know if there is anything already available as a starting point.
A few pointers I found are:

1. [How to read dbus-monitor output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38733/how-to-read-dbus-monitor-output). General info and python code to handle notifications. Also a link to [indicator-notifications](https://github.com/trism/indicator-notifications) (recent-notifications).
2. [Parsing dbus monitor output messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810834/parsing-dbus-monitor-output-messages)
3. https://github.com/tstack/lnav/issues/505

Comment: Is it possible to get that as a structured output, like JSON or something?

Comment: @muru - I am not sure, but please see EDIT at the bottom.

Comment: Is there any way to get this info about a notification that is already displayed? I didn't start `dbus-monitor` before it appeared, and I don't know how to make it re-appear. The text is cut off.

Answer (score 1):

The extension [Expandable Notifications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4463/expandable-notifications/) is just for this purpose. Enable it and you'll see a small expandable triangle besides each notification.

GNOME has this issue tracked at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/753 . If you want to see this feature built into GNOME, please upvote there.

Comment: I installed the extension in Ubuntu 22.10. Unfortunately, calendar messages have been moved to the right side of the Notifications area (just below the calendar), leaving a big empty unused space on the left. This extension does not seem to affect the calendar messages in their new location. However, I'll see if this extension works as advertised when I get a system notification that appears on the left side of the Notifications area.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Notify OSD app? It is quit useful if you want to configure your notifications. You can read more about it here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD

Here are the steps how to install it from the terminal:

```
sudo apt install notify-osd
pkill notify-osd
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install notifyosdconfig
```

Comment: Very interesting - thank you. But that is from Lucid 10.04 days. What is generating these notifications in Bionic 18.04? And how can we get that to log them also? Seems better going forward than installing an alternate(?) app.

Comment: Sorry, how does this answer the question?